# Unknown object in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, colors

I have Word 2013 .docx document with one (or maybe two) object. 
That object have blue color and I would like to turn it on green. 
Color in object progressively turns from blue to white and I would like to have object which color turns from green to white.
Here is link of my file: [Word document](http://tinyurl.com/word-object)

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

completely ignore the one you have (it seems it is an image, because nothing can be done on it)

do the following steps:

- insert a rectangle from "Insert shapes"

[image]

- go to "format" tab.
- click on the green color in styles part.
- go to "shape fill", go to "gradient" and choose the light variation you want!

[image]

now you have the intended rectangle!